# What's really 'third party applications'?

Tags: applications

I would like to know what's really **third party applications** in android.While I was referring [Android development](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Professional_Android_4_Application_Devel.html?id=bmJIl_wPgQsC) it says that application layer consist of:

1. Native apps
2. Third party apps
3. Developer Apps

I know that third party applications are those which are not developed by the first party(provider of the operating system) as mentioned in [third party applications](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-are-third-party-applications.htm).But I think when it comes to android third party apps and developer apps are same isn't it?Could anyone help me.

Comment: I honestly couldn't understand the separation between native apps, 3rd-party apps, and *applications* (all of those are applications on my dictionary). As it was quoted from the book (which we couldn't get access unless we buy it), does it also explain the difference between those, or only mentioning this? If it does, could you also quote and add it on the question?

Comment: @AndrewT.:Oh sorry.It was really _Developer Apps_ not _Applications_ as I edited the posted.Could you tell whether **third party apps** differ from Developer apps.As the answer stated by Izzy both should be same because both are neither developed by the _OS_ nor the _manufacturer_.

Comment: I guess in this context, "developer apps" stands for apps not installed from any "market" – but those you write yourself and test-install via the corresponding development frameworks. In the context of "signatures" (see my answer below): AFAIK those apps are signed with "development keys", so they again have a kind of "special signature". I must investigate deeper into this to tell the exact difference from a user's point of view, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short version

Every app other than "OS and manufacturer apps" means "third party apps".

### TL;DR

Third party apps are those provided by a, hrm, third party. Though the following terms are non-existent, you can visualize this as follows: First party is the one providing the OS (AOSP/Google), second party the manufacturer (adding his own apps).

Basically, this can be read as: Everything that didn't come pre-installed. This is what the term "third party" normally is used for<sup>1</sup>.

### Technical background

You find some technical background in Android's permission system. If you browse the [related pages on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) or see my [App permissions explained](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms), for some permissions you will encounter the phrase "not for use by third party apps" (or similar). How does the system decide what makes a "third party app"? It looks at its [signature](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and compares that to the OS and manufacturers' signatures. If the app's signature doesn't match any of the two, it's a "third party app".

#### "Developer Apps"

In your question, the focus was to decide between "third party" and "developer" apps. Basically, in practice developer apps are rather a "sub-group" of "third party" apps. As the [corresponding developer page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) states, to make debugging an app during development easier<sup>3</sup>, it can be signed "in debug mode":

> You can sign an app in debug or release mode. You sign your app in debug mode during development and in release mode when you are ready to distribute your app. The Android SDK generates a certificate to sign apps in debug mode. To sign apps in release mode, you need to generate your own certificate.
>
> […]
>
> You can run and debug an app signed in debug mode on the emulator and on devices connected to your development manchine through USB, but you cannot distribute an app signed in debug mode.

Thus "developer apps" can be told by using a known "debug certificate". As the quoted source states, this should not be used with "released apps" (e.g. a developer shouldn't publish any app signed this way)<sup>2</sup>.

### Further readings

- [Application Signature Verification: How It Works, How to Disable It with Xposed, and Why You Shouldn’t](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/application-signature-verification-how-it-works-how-to-disable-it-with-xposed-and-why-you-shouldnt/)
- [Android Fake ID Vulnerability Lets Malware Impersonate Trusted Applications](http://www.darkreading.com/d/d-id/1297639) (describes a bug exploited to work around signature protection, allowing any app to pose as "signed by OS or manufacturer", which was fixed e.g. with Kitkat)
- [Android signature mechanism](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1778162/) (describes the difference between "ROM signature mechanism" and "Third party APK Signature mechanism")
- [Digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (general background of what a digital signature is and how it works)

---

<sup>**1:** though technically it might be not fully correct (example: in this context, what would an app be called which you manually installed, when it were signed with the same key as the ROM itself – i.e. was coming from the manufacturer?)</sup>

<sup>**2:** This is for security reasons. Apps might be able to access other apps' resources when using the same signature – a fact used e.g. by "addons" for specific apps written by the same developer (as the [already named source](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) e.g. puts it: *Android allows apps signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a single application.* And: *Android provides signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an app can expose functionality to another app that is signed with a specified certificate. By signing multiple apps with the same certificate and using signature-based permissions checks, your apps can share code and data in a secure manner*). Using "your own" certificate protects "your" app from being accessed by "other developers' apps".</sup>

<sup>**3:** AFAIK you cannot install an "unsigned app", so signing it is a must. When "signing" an app, one usually needs to provide two passwords (one for the keystore holding your signatures, and one for the signature itself). Using "debug mode" signing, this can be avoided, as this uses an internal signature of the SDK with a password known by the development tools. This makes debugging a lot easier, as you don't have to type the two passwords over and over during the "compile › test › compile › test again › .." process.</sup>

Comment: :That's a good elaborative answer.But could you tell is there any need in signing an app in _debug mode_.

Comment: As described by my (again updated) answer: "make debugging an app during development easier". I'll include a little background on that with "yet another update". After that, let's clean up our comments (deleting those obsoleted by my updates to the answer), shall we? ;)

Comment: :Okay.But could you tell me what really means by the _signature_ of an app.Does it mean who really developed it(whether it's OS,manufacturer) or does it mean anything else?

Comment: That's going a little deep into the technical part. You might wish to refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature "Wikipedia: Digital signature") for this. Basically, it means who *signed* the app, which usually is the developer. As with a paper being signed by a (hand-written) signature, a digital signature demonstrates the authenticity of the signed data (here the `.apk`).